# Problema con el assertTrue en java

Tags: java, tdd

Muy buenas, resulta que tengo esta clase Libros

```
    public class Libros {
    String titulo, autor;
    int ejemplaresPrestados, ejemplaresTotales;

    public Libros(String titulo, String autor, int ejemplaresPrestados, int ejemplaresTotales){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.ejemplaresPrestados = ejemplaresPrestados;
        this.ejemplaresTotales = ejemplaresTotales;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public int getEjemplaresPrestados() {
        return ejemplaresPrestados;
    }

    public void setEjemplaresPrestados(int ejemplaresPrestados) {
        this.ejemplaresPrestados = ejemplaresPrestados;
    }

    public int getEjemplaresTotales() {
        return ejemplaresTotales;
    }

    public void setEjemplaresTotales(int ejemplaresTotales) {
        this.ejemplaresTotales = ejemplaresTotales;
    }

    public boolean prestamo(int descontarTotal){
        boolean descontar = false;
        ejemplaresTotales = getEjemplaresTotales();
        if(descontarTotal < ejemplaresTotales) {
            descontar = true;
        }
        System.out.println("EL valor de ejemplares totales es " + ejemplaresTotales);
        System.out.println("EL valor de descontar tota es " + descontarTotal);
        System.out.println("EL valor de la variable booleana descontar es " + descontar);
        return descontar;
    }
}
```

Y en la clase de test tengo esto

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LibrosTest{
    Libros item1 = new Libros("Como programar en java", "Deitel & Deitel", 2, 30);
    @Test
    public void devolucionNegativa(){
        item1.prestamo(40);
        assertTrue("El prestamo se va hacer?", true);
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

El problema está que cuando paso los test, a pesar de que el valor es false porq ue no puede pasar hacer un préstamo si no hay suficientes ejemplares, me pasa el test en verde, y no entiendo por que. He debugueado con prints, los resultados son lo que yo espero, es decir false, pero me pasa en verde las dos condiciones.

Los resultados que me imprimen son los siguientes una vez ha pasado el if del método de préstamo.

```
EL valor de ejemplares totales es 30
EL valor de descontar tota es 40
EL valor de la variable booleana descontar es false

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Aún así el test lo tengo en verde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes cambiar tu test por:

```
public class LibrosTest{
    Libros item1 = new Libros("Como programar en java", "Deitel & Deitel", 2, 30);
    @Test
    public void devolucionNegativa(){
        boolean resultado = item1.prestamo(40);
        assertTrue("El prestamo se va hacer?", resultado);
        assertEquals(false, resultado);
    }
}
```

De esta manera asignas el valor de `devolucionNegativa()` a una variable y luego pruebas lo que quieras.